# Insert other values from drop-down list with macro, but several times

Tags: excel, vba

I make an Excel file that I use to import on a website. However, the values displayed mean nothing to the website, it needs IDs, but it's just not user-friendly. To help my users I said to myself I'll make a drop-down list that will change the value. For example, if you click on Switzerland, it will show 1 in the cell.

I have created one Macro based on the instruction on https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4130-excel-drop-down-list-show-different-value.html

```
    'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range
    selectedNa = Target.Value
        If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Set xRg = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Dropdown_cantons").RefersToRange
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, xRg, 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
      
    End If
End Sub
```

For the first column it's ok

For my second collone with the cities this time, I thought I would change the collone numbers and follow the instructions in the link above. Maybe I can't put two macros in one Excel?

I tried to do it as a module, but it doesn't work for the second collone either. Do you have an idea?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a great description of exactly what happens when you run your code, and you've only shown us part of your working code, so we have no idea what changes you made.  FYI you can only have one "change" event handler per worksheet, so you will need to combine both sets of code into a single Sub, and within that sub (maybe based on `Target.Column`) you can decide how to handle the change.

Answer (score 1):

Could look something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handle single-cell changes
    Select Case Target.Column
        'depending on the column number, call `SetId` with specific arguments
        Case 3: SetId Target, ActiveWorkbook.Names("Dropdown_cantons").RefersToRange, 2
        Case 4: SetId Target, ActiveWorkbook.Names("Dropdown_countries").RefersToRange, 2
    End Select
End Sub

'translate a data validation drop-down "text" selection into a matching "id" value
Sub SetId(c As Range, rngTable As Range, returnCol As Long)
    Dim v, res
    
    v = c.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        res = Application.VLookup(v, rngTable, returnCol, False) 'find the id
        If Not IsError(res) Then                     'got a match
            On Error GoTo haveError                  'ensure we exit with events back on
            Application.EnableEvents = False         'disable events
            c.Value = res                            'switch the value
            Application.EnableEvents = True          're-enable events
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub                                         'normal exit
    
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True                  'just in case....
End Sub
```